# How do I initialise state in Nuxt.js which includes localStorage while Universal Rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, nuxt.js

#### Scenario

First of all, let me start with my flow. 
I am storing token in localStorage (I know I shouldn't do it.)
Then, whenever my Nuxt App is started, I want to fetch token from localStorage, verify it using API call, and initialise state accordingly.

#### Problem

I am using Server Side Rendering and Nuxt initialises state Server Side. Thus, localStorage is not accessible there.

#### Proposed Workaround

I created an Action which does task explained in `Scenario` and that action is triggered from mounted() of `layouts/default.vue`

**Can Anyone Please suggest a Better Workflow or Can Verify Wether this is Correct Way of doing things?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use `typeof window === 'undefined'`  to determine if it running in Server Side, and skip the code you only want to run in client, just like:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   // your code
}
```

You can use it in `created`/`beforeCreate`/`asyncData` , And if you code is in mounted(), you may not need do this, 'case this Lifecycle Hooks only run in the client.

Comment: ```
if(process.client){
   //execute on the client not the server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Middleware and dispatch your action that checks the token in it and call it in the layout.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware